# MYSQL enquiry on outputting a query with duplicate fields from a table

Tags: mysql

I have a database with table named "Stats"
I have field called "Seasons" with entries:
"Summer", "Spring", "winter", "autumn"

And from the table "Sales"
I'm wanting "number of sales" with entries that would require COUNT

My desired output is:

```
Season|number of sales|    
-----------------------
Summer     22  

Season|number of sales|    
------------------------
Winter     30
```

I have managed to get this so far:

```
    Season     number of sales    
------------------------------
    Summer     22    
    Winter     30
```

But am needing repetition of the **header fields** (Season & Number Of Sales)

Could anyone help please?

Comment: Your example output data is identical (except a different sort-order). I don't understand what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is right you need to have column names appear with every row. Though I don't see a practical usage but you may be using them in different grids and populating grid columns from DB. 
 The simplest of all here is : Select multiple times. 
With each query having a where clause of particular `Season = "Summer"` and like. 
 If you want to save on DB iterations or hits you may take the entire select in Table variable and select from it accordingly.